# What book had a robot going around the galaxy, making other robots?

Tags: story-identification, books, space, soft-sci-fi, humor

I remember getting recommended a book about a robot travelling around the galaxy making other robots. However, I never had a chance to read and have now forgotten its title.

My recollection is unfortunately very lacking, but I do remember that he makes for instance one robot that only can make things that start with a specific letter. It's a sci-fi book with plenty of humour. I think the cover of the book had a robot on the front page and was mostly red and/or red and black.

Does anyone have aaany idea what book I'm thinking about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds very much like [*The Cyberiad*](http://english.lem.pl/works/novels/the-cyberiad) by Stanislaw Lem:

> One day Trurl the constructor put together a machine that could create
>   anything starting with n.
>   [from [*How the World was Saved*](http://english.lem.pl/works/novels/the-cyberiad/146-how-the-world-was-saved)]

Comment: Seconded. It's actually a series of short stories about a pair of robot inventors.

Comment: I don't think I remember that cover, but from the summary that sounds like the book! Great, thanks!

Comment: After googling, THIS is the cover I remember http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JDqe9kDTL._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg So yes, you're very right!

Comment: ... a pair of _rival_ robot inventors!  much fun ensues ...